# My booking form won't stay on one line

Tags: css, forms, line

Please check [Samui Green Hotel](http://www.samuigreenhotel.com) ,

When the page opens, the booking fields are nicely added in 1 line (check-in, check-out, adults, children and 'check availability'). For some reason, it is pushed onto 2 separate lines straight after.

I don't have any code to add as I simply don't know where to look for it. Is this a simple CSS issue?

Comment: It does? I get this: [link](http://imgur.com/4QgVPi9) in both Edge and Chrome.

Comment: Do you want all 4 fields in one line?

Comment: yes thats the idea, and the button too

Comment: I think they are too wide to be in one line. Perhaps some media queries are stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.input-group-addon .form-control { width: 25%; }
```

If you see no change:

```
.input-group-addon .form-control { width: 25% !important; }
```

If it changed but it's still two rows then decrease the 25%.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
.large .enable-bootstrap .col-md-6, .extra-large .enable-bootstrap .col-md-6            
width: 20%;
}
```

instead of

```
.large .enable-bootstrap .col-md-6, .extra-large .enable-bootstrap .col-md-6 {
width: 50%;
```

}